# Reusing Eigen expression templates

Tags: c++, math, eigen

Let's say I have 4 matrices that are constant, and 1 matrix that is variable:

`Eigen::MatrixXf M,N,O,P; // Fixed`

`Eigen::MatrixXf Q; // Value changes`

And I have an expression that I wish to evaluate:

`auto myExpression = M*N*O*P*Q;`

if I were to do the following:

`for (int i = 0; i<5; ++i) {`

`Q = MatrixXf::Random(SomeSize,SomeSize);`

`MatrixXf result = myExpression.eval();`

`}`

Would this work as expected? Meaning I get the correct result from the new value of Q?

Comment: Independent from the fact that this works in 3.3, it is a bad idea, unless you intentionally want to obfuscate your code and make it incompatible with Eigen 3.2 ...

Comment: would this help performance?

Answer (score 1):

In Eigen 3.3, the answer is yes... unless your expression involves matrix factorizations like:

```
auto expr = M.lu().solve(O+P)+N*Q;
```

In Eigen 3.2, you must in addition be careful with matrix products because those are evaluated immediately.

Comment: Thanks. Out of curiosity, does the same apply for sparse matrices?

Comment: @NOP: In 3.3 this is also true for sparse-sparse or mixed sparse-dense products. Be aware that this is not a good idea to exploit this. Generally, you should only store expression templates if you know what you are doing.